# See processes which use device

Tags: hardware, webcam, process

I have this (hopefully) irrational fear someone might hijack my webcam, especially since some of my colleagues started to put some tape around theirs.

For some reason I am sometimes not able to access /dev/video0 while using skype. 
A while ago I made the experience that only one process can access my camera.

How can I find out which process (if?) is currently using my webcam?
Also how can I unmount and re-mount the webcam?

Thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$ lsof /dev/video0
```

Should tell you which processes are accessing the device, if any.

Comment: Seems nothing is accessing it. How to mount/unmount it?

Comment: You don't `mount` a video device - for testing just fire up any app that makes use of it ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auditd` to monitor your video device, and it will log it to `/var/log/audit/auditd.log`. It will tell you what application is accessing the device. Pretty cool.

Comment: A complete answer would have how to use the auditd command.