# Camera turns on on startup

Tags: startup, webcam, privacy

I have a laptop which has ubuntu 19.10 on it.
Every time I start my computer, the LED indicator for the web cam turns on.

why is it happening ?

Update 1:
I ran `ls -ltrh /dev/video*`
and got:

`crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Mar 23 10:10 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Mar 23 10:10 /dev/video0`

than I ran `lsof video0` and `lsof video1` while the led indicator was on and got nothing

Comment: Does this help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/582153/see-processes-which-use-device

Comment: It does not return anything to me. could it be just the led ?

Comment: You should do just some tests? Is it always on? When you try to use the camera what happens? You can try to open the camera with VLC (Media >> Open Capture Device). Please, [edit] your question and add all the available info and test results. Do not post comments.